# Apache sites-available default and other

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

i have a domain name called for example "mydomain.com"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
....
</VirtualHost>
```

When i write the following address in url:

www.mydomain.com/mysubdomain/myfolder

go to a web page working fine.

mysubdomain sites-available is the following, called mysubdomain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysubdomain
    ServerName www.mysubdomain.com
        ServerAlias mysubdomain.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_mysubdomain.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_mysubdomain.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/mysubdomain>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works fine, when i type `www.mydomain.com/mysubdomain/myfolder` goes fine to
`www.mydomain.com/mysubdomain/myfolder/login.php`

but when i write

http://www.mysubdomain.com/myfolder/login.php

don´t work as expected, because when i include in login.php a ref, like `../../myfolder` can´t go to root folder as i expected, how can i fix it ?

in `www.mydomain.com/mysubdomain/myfolder/login.php` the ref like `../../myfolder` go fine to `/var/www/`

i want that the url showing to user could be `http://www.mysubdomain.com/myfolder/login.php`

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs are relative to the **URL**, not to the file system on the web server (which is invisible to the client).

You can't navigate up the directory tree to a file which doesn't appear under the web root for the virtual host being viewed.

Comment: How can i solve the issue ? I need to access the root folder /var/www/ because i have php code there, and i need to include it in my code.

Comment: Adding an "Alias" as in my answer solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:

change the file mysubdomain that is in sites-available to

DocumentRoot /var/www/mysubdomain
    ServerName www.mysubdomain.com
        ServerAlias mysubdomain.com

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_mysubdomain.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_mysubdomain.log combined

Alias /myfolder /var/www/myfolder

<Directory /var/www/mysubdomain>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```